# win7 not acknwledging external USB HD as "removable"

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

Win7 does not mark my external HD as "removable".

Consistently I do not have an "eject" entry in the context menu.

Curiosely the "safely remove" widget **does** list the drive, but then fails because "in use".

This happens with several different external HDs, never with USB "keys".

I checked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/197661/how-do-i-make-my-external-usb-hdd-be-treated-as-a-removable-drive) and now Recycle Bin & System Protection are inactivated for this drive, but "Elements" is still non-removable.

What should I check?

How can I safely remove it? (aside from just yanking the cable, of course!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [External HDD is always in use when trying to safely remove](http://superuser.com/questions/510968/external-hdd-is-always-in-use-when-trying-to-safely-remove)

Comment: Not really; see my own (partial) answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record:
[How do I make my external USB HDD be treated as a removable drive](https://superuser.com/questions/197661/how-do-i-make-my-external-usb-hdd-be-treated-as-a-removable-drive) **is** the right answer.

Problem is you have to reboot (or yank the cable one last time) before it takes hold.

If the USB drive was already mounted you won't be able to eject it, even if you stop "Recycle Bin" and "System Protection".

ONE REMAINING QUESTION: Now I'm able to "safely remove" my external HD, but it *still* shows up as "Fixed Drive" with no "Eject"option in context menu.  Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ZioByte's answer, you can "Eject" the hdd as follows:

1. Click Windows icon in task bar. 
   Click on **Run…**
2. Type:

   > RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll
3. Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or click on “**OK**”.
4. In the “Safely Remove Hardware” dialog click on the device you want to remove, and press Stop.

Also answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1090193/windows-10-no-option-to-eject-external-hard-drive-not-usb-stick#1344325)