# Flagging an external SSD as removable

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, filesystems, removable-media

I recently bought an external SSD ([SanDisk Extreme Pro](https://shop.westerndigital.com/de-de/products/portable-drives/sandisk-extreme-pro-usb-3-1-ssd#SDSSDE80-500G-G25)), and I would like to flag it as a removable device. I did some research before asking it here:

1. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1359208
2. https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/111728-how-make-disk-drive-removable.html
3. [How do I make my external USB HDD be treated as a removable drive](https://superuser.com/questions/197661/how-do-i-make-my-external-usb-hdd-be-treated-as-a-removable-drive)

All these addresses lead to a dead-end. Nevertheless I found a hint in ubuntuforums (1):

> For my little thumb drive, the value of /sys/block/sd*/removable is 1.

> For my main external drive, the value of /sys/block/sd*/removable is 0.

**So in someway I need to change the above value to 1. However it is not easy like open up notebook, change to 1, and save. Is there a way to do that? or any other approach to change the external device to "removable"-flagged.**

Why I need this:

I would like to install Tails (a linux distro) into this SSD. However, Tails only works with removable drives.

There is a way to boot Tails with non-removable devices; boot-options and remove "live-media=removable", but I don't wanna remove this part every time from boot, when I want to boot Tails.

One can also change some files in the system, so removing live-media part would be saved for boot. However, I am not a computer genius and I also don't know what I am exactly doing.

Therefore, I follow tutorials, and these tutorials are old and/or not compatible with every device.

Additionally tutorials should be repeated for every upgrade on Tails system. That is why I though the best option would be changing the devices non-removable flag.